# why it become slow in oracle11g after continue do one row insert with jdbc

Tags: performance, oracle11g, insert

I write a code to test performance of one row insert in oracle11g.
But find that the latency will become slow after few minute.

The test way is write a single thread, and do insert one row record(data size 1K+) loop with jdbc. 
And control the insert speed in 200 tps

I want got an stable performance

but actual result is not, in the beigin, the latency is 0.9ms+, it's good, after few minute, the latency come to 4~5ms, which is so bad performance.

the detail show below:

test env:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz
memory size: 64G
SSD
```

in latency=0.9ms+, the iostat

```
iostat -mx 1
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           9.67    0.00    0.75    1.00    0.00   88.57

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     1.00    0.00  447.00     0.00     2.70    12.35     0.12    0.27    0.00    0.27   0.26  11.40
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00  448.00     0.00     2.70    12.32     0.12    0.27    0.00    0.27   0.25  11.30
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

in latency=4~5ms, the iostat

```
iostat -mx 1
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           9.36    0.00    0.84    4.85    0.00   84.95

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00  400.00     0.00     0.80     4.10     0.59    1.47    0.00    1.47   1.47  58.80
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00  400.00     0.00     0.80     4.10     0.59    1.47    0.00    1.47   1.47  58.80
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: I try another  test case,  change the test env(Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz  16G  HDD disk),   these problem had gone.   So  it's because of SSD?